# How do I change the size of a movieclip in flash by clicking on it? (Actionscript 3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, resize, movieclip

Everything I've found is for making a separate button, but I'm trying to make it so that clicking on the movieclip itself makes it change size. The reason is that it's being animated moving across the page, so clicking it is the challenge. Can anyone help? This is the code I tried:

```
info_btn_mc.buttonMode = true;

info_btn_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openInfo);
    stop();
    function openInfo(e:MouseEvent):void {
            enemy_first.play("shrink");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use play("shrink"), the method 
[play()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#play()) (Moves the playhead in the timeline of the movie clip) has no arguments. use gotoAndPlay/gotoAndStop instead that received an argument called frame:Object (frame number or label (String).

```
 enemy_first.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openInfo);
 enemy_first.stop();

function openInfo(event:MouseEvent):void
{
     trace('event.currentTarget:', event.currentTarget);
     event.currentTarget.gotoAndPlay("shrink");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! I tried your code, and I'm getting an error saying "Symbol 'Symbol 6', Layer 'shrink', Frame 1, Line 2, Column 2 1120: Access of undefined property enemy_first." Symbol 6 is the name of the symbol in the library, and shrink is the name of the layer inside the movieclip. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, since I named the object "enemy_first" in the properties.

Comment: check if the 'event.currentTarget' is really your enemy_first or if you have the same addEventListener in other object as well, like your info_btn_mc (you should remove this listener or create a different method)

Comment: the info_btn_mc is gone, but I still have the error. I use the symbol somewhere else, but I tried deleting it and I still got the error. Nothing seems to be using the same addEventListener.

Comment: I've tried the edited version of your code and I'm getting the same error for both lines (right where enemy_first starts).